# Data Transformation in AWS EMR without using Scala or Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I have a star schema kind of database structure, like one fact table having all the id’s & skeys, whereas there are multiple dimension tables having the actual id, code, descriptions for the id’s referred in the fact table.

we are moving all these tables (fact & dimensions) to S3 (cloud) individually and each table data are split into multiple parquet files in S3 location (one S3 object per table)

Query: i need to perform a transformation on cloud (ie) i need strip of all the id’s & skeys referred in the fact table and replace it with the actual code that is residing in the dimension tables and create another file and store the final output back in S3 location. This file will later be consumed by Redshift for Analytics.

My Doubt:
Whats the best way to achieve this solution, cos i don’t need raw data (skeys & id’s) in Redshift for cost and storage optimization?
Do we need to first combine these split files (parquet) into one large file (ie) before performing the data transformation. Also, after data transformation, I am planning to save the final output file in parquet format, but the catch is, Redshift doesn’t allow copy of parquet file, so is there a workaround for that
I am not a hardcore programmer and want to avoid using scala/python in a EMR, but I am good at SQL, so is there a way to perform data transformation in cloud thru SQL thru EMR and save the output data into a file or files. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run redshift type queries directly against your s3 parquet data by using amazon athena

some information on that
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/